# JS mass listener cleanup on an element

Tags: javascript, listener, dom-events

Is there a simple way to clean up all active listeners on an object so that it can be garbage collected?

e.g. `myDiv.removeAllListeners()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Listeners on an object won't prevent it from being garbage collected. You can simplify it like this:

You have an array. You put functions (listeners) in the array and then throw away your reference to the array. The array is referenced by nothing, so it can be garbage collected. Also, there are no more references to the functions, so that isn't an issue either.